# jQuery ajax call to remote website from local filesystem

Tags: jquery

Ey!

Ok, i've come to understand that you can use AJAX calls to remote servers if your site is running on the local filesystem (using the file:// protocol). Yet using ajax calls with jquery fails every time.

```
        $.ajax({
            url: "https://dokus.no/products/",
            username: "user",
            password: "password",
            dataType: "json",
            isLocal: true,
            success: function() {alert("hhohoho");},
            error: function(jq, text, exception) {alert("fail");}
        });
```

Comment: Where do you have this information from? I don't think this is true in any browser.

Comment: Certain browsers will not allow cross-domain requests if the server provides a certain header in response (Access-Control-Allow-Origin). As far as I know the only other way to do this from the local file system is through a desktop or mobile application using something like Adobe AIR, PhoneGap, Titanium, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thats only supported by certain browsers, and you need to turn it on.

You are running into the same-origin-policy issue, where a browser will refuse to send an xhr (ajax request) if the url for the ajax request doesn't meet very specific requirements.